# How do I use a method compositionally with another method

Tags: java

I honestly don't know how to approach this, what's meant to happen is that when the user inputs the distance in the move method for class Player, the players position moves accordingly. I also want the position for Jar to move the same amount based on the distance the player has moved.

```
public class Player
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String name;
    private int position;
    private Jar jar;

    public Player()
    {
        position = 0;
        jar = new Jar();

        System.out.print("Enter player's name: ");
        this.name = Global.keyboard.nextLine();

    }

    public int move(int distance)
    {
        position = position + distance;
    }
}


public class Jar
{
    private int position;
    private Stone stone;


    public Jar()
    {
        position = 0;
        stone = null;
    }

    public Jar(int initPos, Stone stone)
    {
        position = initPos;
        this.stone = stone;
    }

     public void move()
    {
        Player move = new Player();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you store `position` in both classes?

Comment: It was a requirement, they are different positions, the position of the jar and the position of the player.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is use the move method from the player class to move the jar as well by the same amount

Comment: Then maybe you should have a method like `moveByDistance(int distance){this.position += distance;}` in `Jar`, and call `this.jar.moveByDistance(distance);` in `Player.move` as a second statement.

Comment: Bro I have added my answer check it. If it works, upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the `Jar` position from within the `Player`. Also, you probably don't want to create a new `Player`everytime you change position.

```
public class Player {

    ...

    public int move(int distance) {
        position = position + distance;
        jar.move(distance);
    }
}


public class Jar {
    private int position;
    private Stone stone;

    public Jar() {
        position = 0;
        stone = null;
    }

    public Jar(int initPos, Stone stone) {
        position = initPos;
        this.stone = stone;
    }

     public void move(int distance) {
        position += distance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the method to void because there is no reason to return a value
 When the move method gets a distance value. It will change the position of the Player class instance as well It will call the Jar instance move method.
When Jar Class Instance move method is called then jar position also be changed Look at the Jar Move method

````
public class Player
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String name;
    private int position;
    private Jar jar;

    public Player()
    {
        position = 0;
        jar = new Jar();

        System.out.print("Enter player's name: ");
        this.name = Global.keyboard.nextLine();

    }

    public void move(int distance)
    {
        position = position + distance;
        jar.move(distance); 
    }
}


public class Jar
{
    private int position;
    private Stone stone;


    public Jar()
    {
        position = 0;
        stone = null;
    }

    public Jar(int initPos, Stone stone)
    {
        position = initPos;
        this.stone = stone;
    }

     public void move( int distance)
    {
       position = position+distance;
    }
}
```
````